# set parameter in play framework action within template

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a single input form in a play scala template:

```
@helper.form(action=routes.Application.searchResult()) {
     <input type="text" name="userQuery" value="@userQuery">
}
```

and would like to pass an extra parameter, '@channel' to the searchResult action, which it takes as an optional argument.

@channel is passed as an argument to the current template. What's the simplest way to do this?

I tried replacing

```
routes.Application.searchResult()
```

with

```
routes.Application.searchResult(channel=channel)
```

with no success

Answer (score -1):

Either you update the route to the action to pass parameter by there, or you use form mapping with corresponding parameter parser.